# How to drop an entry from the okhttp3 cache

Tags: android, caching, webview, okhttp

Because my app is using custom tabs for authentication and then returning to the app need where the page that was redirected to login might still be loaded into the webview (or recalled upon return from the custom tab) can I clear a page's cache entry without forcing a network call?

It would be nice, at different places in my app, to check and see if there is an entry in the cache for a given page. The real request is to be able to remove/overwrite a cache entry without forcing a network call since the user may not immediately return to the page they were viewing when login was required.

Answer (score 4):

> The cache has an iterator which supports remove()

I got a great solution from the okhttp3 team [to call urls](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html#urls--) and use the Iterator to see the cache contents. One note of caution, it is possible to delete the webview's currently loaded page from the cache which has unexpected results.

Thanks Square!